# how to rid index.php and variables from GET method

Tags: windows, iis-7, web-config

I need to change www.mysite.pl/?title=title-of-my-site&id=123 to www.mysite.pl/some-text/123/

in my web.config:

```
<rule name="topic" >
    <match url="^topic\/([_0-9a-z-A-Z-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?title={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

and with this configurations changing to www.mysite.pl/some-text/123/index.php?title=title-of-my-site&id=123

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem was with PHP code where is a lot of redirecting, which depending on url pattern. e.g:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index.php")===false and $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']<>"" and strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "topic")===false and strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "pattern1,")===false and strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "pattern2,")===false and strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "error_page")===false) {
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: index.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
die();
}
```